# JSP Iterating over a map of a list when the value might be null

Tags: jsp, struts2, guava

**How do I clear the value from the stack of a s:iterator?**

I'm trying to iterator over a TreeMultimap with a structure like:

```
TreeMultimap<person, lineItems> persons;
```

Using something like:

```
<s:iterator value="attendeesForParticipantTypeEvents.asMap()">
  <div>
    <s:property value="key.name" /><br />
    <s:iterator var="currentSku" value="value">
      <s:property value="currentSku.name" /><br />
    </s:iterator>
  </div>
</s:iterator>
```

This works fine, except when the treeMultimap has null for lineItems, then it's taking the value from the previous iteration.

So, a structure like:

```
persons = {{"Person1",["Line1","line2"]},
           {"Person2",["Line3","line4"]},
           {"Person3",null}}
```

Renders as:

```
<div>
   Person1<br />
   Line1<br />
   Line2<br />
</div>
<div>
   Person2<br />
   Line3<br />
   Line4<br />
</div>
<div>
   Person3<br />
   Line3<br />
   Line4<br />
</div>
```

Which seems to indicate that the value isn't being cleared on each iterator.  What do I need to do to handle the case where value might be null?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I would like to know which struts2 version you were using id was deprecated http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/iterator.html

Comment: I copied that wrong from my code, we are using var, and are on Struts 2.2.3

Comment: I think when there are no lineItems, you will get an empty TreeSet<LineItems>, and not a null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you pre-filter the map before delivering it to Struts/JSP. Seperation of concerns dictates that your presentation layer shouldn't be making that sort of decisions.

I belive that Multimap cannot (and certainly should not) have null values; so your structure would likely be:

```
persons = {{"Person1",["Line1","line2"]},
           {"Person2",["Line3","line4"]},
           {"Person3",[]}}
```

Comment: But I do want to show all of the key records, not just the key records with line items in a single HTML list.  How would the pre-filter make that easier?

Comment: Brian; I would suggest instead of representing a key with no values as null you use just an empty collection, that should solve your problem.